# custom_variables value not in quotes

Tags: surveymonkey

I have just downloaded a get_survey_details.json and note that the question_id value is not quoted. I would have expected "623478675" Is this a change?

{"status": 0, "data": {"custom_variables": [{"variable_label": "User Agent", "question_id": 623478675}

Comment: This is a bug in the API, I'll report it to get fixed in the next release.